# What is the use of Legend Trophies?

Tags: clash-royale

I've noticed that at the end of Clash Royale seasons, top players with over 3000 trophies will have the excess trophies converted into *Legend Trophies*.
**What is the use of them? Do they have an actual use or are they just for show?**

Comment: There point is to look cool and you can tell your friends you have legend trophies.

Answer (score 3):

That's a great question, I actually don't think about that.

For now, it looks like there is **no use** of Legend Trophy. It may just showing how "legendary" this player is, but we still don't know.

And according to the [wiki page](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Arenas#Legendary_Arena), there is no statements of the use of legend trophies.

Comment: One slight footnote - though they seem to offer nothing other than prestige - they do remain indefinitely.  That, I believe is there point.  Once you earn them, you'll always have them to show off, come what may.

Answer (score -5):

When Gotten Legendary Trophies and getting 35000 trophies. There's a hidden arena called Heroe of Heroes Arena. My cousin has 36009 and I saw this. This is a whole new Arena with A Gigantic dragon is the statue In it.
Mike My cousin HAS gotten it 24 days ago. He plays it a lot .

Comment: can you provide any source for this?

Comment: If it's hidden, it's hard to get an official source. Also, it is EXTREMELY HARD to get 35000 Legendary Trophies. Nevertheless, it's very interesting. @Dragonrage

Comment: @John i highly doubt his cousin has gotten 35000 trophies. 3500 maybe, but there are a number of people who have gotten over 3500 trophies. if there was really a hidden arena, there would be some proof of it.

Comment: Perhaps he hacked them in. @Dragonrage

Comment: as far as I understand it, your legendary trophies add up so you can have 35k if your really good, cant you?